# On Flutter Parsing Json in The Background fails

Tags: json, parsing, flutter

I try to implement the Parsing JSON in the background on https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/background-parsing/ and I am getting bellow error. Error also same when I use the Android Emulator.

I am using macOs HighSierra. I install IntelliJ and Fluter and Dark plugin. I test most examples on Flutter and it all worked. I also created a demo up and its working. I don't understand why this not working. Any Help please?

**Code I am using:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


// JSON::WEATHER 
Future<String> getWeatherData() async {
  var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=San+Francisco&units=metric&APPID=14cc828bff4e71286219858975c3e89a"),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
  );

  this.setState(() {
     weatherData = json.decode(response.body);
  });

  return 'Success!';
}


@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();;
  this.getWeatherData();
}


// USAGE
new Text(
         weatherData['list'][0]['main']['temp_min'].toString(),
         style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 10.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Colors.white,
         ),
),
```

> Launching lib/main.dart on SM G935F in debug mode...
>       Initializing gradle...
>       Resolving dependencies...
>       Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
>       Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk (31.4MB).
>       I/FlutterActivityDelegate(26125): onResume setting current activity to this
>       **D/libGLESv2(26125): STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground**
>       Syncing files to device SM G935F...
>       F/flutter (26125): [FATAL:flutter/fml/message_loop.cc(23)] Check failed: loop != nullptr.
>   MessageLoop::EnsureInitializedForCurrentThread was not called on this
>   thread prior to message loop use.
>       F/libc    (26125): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 26165 (1.ui)
>       *****               *****
>       Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hero2ltexx/hero2lte:7.0/NRD90M/G935FXXS2DRC3:user/release-keys'
>       Revision: '9'
>       ABI: 'arm64'
>       pid: 26125, tid: 26165, name: 1.ui  >>> com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground <<<
>       signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
>       Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/fml/message_loop.cc(23)] Check failed: loop != nullptr.
>   MessageLoop::EnsureInitializedForCurrentThread was not called on this
>   thread prior to message loop use.
>       '
>           x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000006635  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
>           x4   000000000000015f  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000007286ce8000  x7   0000000000000000
>           x8   0000000000000083  x9   ffffffffffffffdf  x10  0000000000000000  x11  ffffffffffffffff
>           x12  0000000000000018  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  000bbc6bf4faa710
>           x16  00000072840caee0  x17  0000007284073a28  x18  000000726095d160  x19  000000725d9ab4f8
>           x20  0000000000000006  x21  000000725d9ab450  x22  0000000000000000  x23  000000725d9ab020
>           x24  000000725d9ab038  x25  000000725d9ab040  x26  000000725d9ab060  x27  000000725d9ab098
>           x28  000000725d9ab009  x29  000000725d9aab00  x30  0000007284070ebc
>           sp   000000725d9aaae0  pc   0000007284073a30  pstate 0000000060000000
>       backtrace:
>           #00 pc 000000000006ca30  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
>           #01 pc 0000000000069eb8  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
>           #02 pc 0000000000024198  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
>           #03 pc 000000000001c9b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
>           #04 pc 00000000003a6d2c  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #05 pc 00000000003a7474  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #06 pc 000000000016dab4  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #07 pc 000000000015f404  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #08 pc 0000000000189b70  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #09 pc 0000000000190b50  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #10 pc 0000000000190674  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #11 pc 00000000001921e8  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #12 pc 00000000005dc220  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #13 pc 0000000000830f4c  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #14 pc 0000000000830df8  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #15 pc 000000000074d084  /data/app/com.yourcompany.parsingjsonintheackground-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so
>           #16 pc 00000000000696bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
>           #17 pc 000000000001dbf0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
>       Lost connection to device.

Comment: Please provide the code and other information that allows to reproduce. What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: I will do it tomorrow

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I update my question with code...

Comment: I think it's a bug. If you create a bug report, it would be great if you could provide a GitHub repo with a project that allows to reproduce. You also need to guard agains `weatherData` being `null` in `// USAGE`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I will do it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer here it is: h**ps://github.com/NTMS2017/ntmsweather

Comment: Is there a reason you replace `tt` with `**`?

Comment: Can you please report a bug in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer. for tt no reason. its old habits. I repot the bug in link you provide. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I answered in the related bug you opened:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16738

Comment: I saw the issue with the not awaited future as well, but the error message seems a bit weird for accessing a `Future` instead of the actual value, don't you think as well?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I accessed value to early. So after I moved the weather section in separate widget its worked as I expected.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the error I got when I ran the code from the above repo was more helpful:

`    The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state:`

`    _MyHomePageState#f6428):`

`    The method '[]' was called on null.`

`    Receiver: null`
`    Tried calling: []("list")`
`    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:`
`    #0      Object.noSuchMethod` `(dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:46:5)`
`   #1      _MyHomePageState.buildWeather` `(file:///Users/mit/tmp/ntmsweather/lib/main.dart:124:38)`

Comment: @MichaelThomsen that's more like what I had expected